# problem with resx files Compiler Error Message: CS0101

Tags: compiler-construction, message

In .NET application I have four different resx file with different name

UITranslation.ba-Latn-BA.resx
UITranslation.hr-HR.resx
UITranslation.resx
UITranslation.sr-Cyrl-BA.resx

Solution is publised on Windows server 2003 Service pack 1. After browse from iis I got following error:

Line 24:     [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 25:     [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
Line 26:     public class UITranslation {
Line 27:
Line 28:         private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

If files are renamed into:

UITranslation**1**.ba-Latn-BA.resx
UITranslation**2**.hr-HR.resx
UITranslation**3**.resx
UITranslation.sr-Cyrl-BA.resx

everithing works.

Files nead to be named as in first case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the application or in its deployment procedure. Unofortunatelly the problem lies in the Windows Server 2003 SP 1 system. To fix it you need to upgrade from SP 1 to SP 2.